# How to design back-end for a Computer Vision application

Tags: computer-vision, backend

Suppose I have a series of Neural Networks that produce some interpretation of a video input (for example classify objects and provide pose estimation of each human in the frame)

I want to build an application that displays that video, mapping the outputs of networks onto the video - i.e. a person walking with a frame around them with the label `human` and their [pose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pW6nZXeWlGM) (joints and limbs)

My question is what's the best place to start for designing the back-end for such application - assuming the processing of videos with the CNN will happen on cloud and will return the output that has to be displayed in near real time

Specifically, what platform or language I should be using and if there are any considerations that will determine which implementation is the best

> Note: I appreciate that this question is very generic but I'm simply looking for a place to start (assume I have no proper software development training)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the object detection/calssification model trained and capable of detecting the desired objects

This is the usual pipeline below for detecting object and saving it as video

```
1. Read the video frames using opencv [You can use moviepy as well]
2. For each  frame : a) Preprocess the frame before sending to the network
                b) Get the output as coordinates
                c) Use opencv to draw the predicted bounding box along with the classified label in the frame
                d) Add the current frame to the new video_writer object of opencv
                e) Finally save it as a video

3. Display the video
```

If we are planning to create a web app which accept a video as input and show the prediction dynamically in realtime,

Make use of web sockets to send each frame to the server [High end machine as you said] to process the image and get the image back as response and display in page

Please go through the Links given below to get more idea on this :

```
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/object-detection-on-drone-videos-using-caffe-framework
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ai-developer-project-part-3-combating-distracted-driver-behavior
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Is there a way to make this local? Suppose we have a GPU locally attached to a video capturing camera - is there a way to capture the video, process it locally with a CNN - to for example classify men and women and then send the processed data to the server?